# SendGrid using NodeJS with Fetch - 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, fetch, sendgrid, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request from the SendGrid Web API when I'm trying to send the following request to SendGrid via fetch with NodeJS:

```
 var emailBody = {
 "personalizations":[
    {
       "to":[
          {
             "email":"some_email@gmail.com"
          }
       ]
    }
 ],
 "from":{
    "email": "some_email@gmail.com"
 },
 "subject": "Send Grid",
 "content": [
    {
       "type":"text/plain",
      "value": "Send Grid msg"
    }
 ]
};

var emailOptions = {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + [API_Key],
  'content-type': 'application/json'
},
body: emailBody
 };
fetch(sendGridUrl, emailOptions)
```

The request works in Postman using the same payload.

Comment: Anything else that they send in their response that might help?
Usually a Bad Request is sent if the request isn't properly constructed. You might want to double check whether the exact same request gets passed from Postman.

Comment: This is what I get from the res.json  "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Bad Request",
            "field": null,
            "help": null
        }
    ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from the `node-fetch` documentation seems to indicate that you need to use `JSON.stringify()` on the `body`.

Quote:

```
var body = { a: 1 };
fetch('http://httpbin.org/post', { 
    method: 'POST',
    body:    JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

From: https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch#usage

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  I thought this would have automatically been taken care of?  When using mailGun; there's no need for the stringify.